# Can I see a list of all push actions on origin?

Tags: git, jenkins, push, commit

Our Jenkins monitors our git repository and starts a specific job each time something has changed on it.  Changes happen whenever a push action has been performed.

Later I would like to see what triggered the build of the Jenkins job, and, obviously, it is a push action, but the git commands I know of only show me the log of the commits, not of the push actions.  But it can happen that some developer works locally, commits lots of stuff and much later pushes all their commits to origin, thus triggers a Jenkins job build.

Is there a way to see which commits have been pushed with which push action and when this happened?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible with git alone. Git itself does not track or log this kind of information.

A solution depends on what other software you use and how it is configured.

- If you use git polling in Jenkins, there is a polling log you can look at. There may be something similar if you use hooks.
- If you use something like gitolite, there is an access log. It is rather low-level and contains a lot of data but you should be able to find everything.